# Calling WPF Control Library

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, casting, window

When I want to show user a (windows) form which resides in a DLL (in this case Form1), I use the following code from another executable;

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("mydll.dll"));
Form MyDLLFormInstance = (Form)a.CreateInstance("myNamespace.Form1");
MyDLLFormInstance.Show();
```

Now, I created another DLL using WPF. When I use the above code, I got the following error;

```
Unable to cast object of type 'myNamespace.Window1' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'.
```

So, How can I cast System.Windows.Window to System.Windows.Forms.Form? Or, how can I show the window which resides in a WPF-created-DLL from c# forms app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly cast a *System.Windows.Window* to *System.Windows.Forms.Form*.

However, it is possible to create a windows form and use it to host a WPF control as a child control.

Windows Forms provides the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control for this.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this answer.